# Search for a cell's value in another sheet, colour it, and repeat

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with two sheet. I want to take a value in sheet1 (ex: cell A1), search it in sheet2, and colour that cell or row if it matches.

I'd also like to know if this can be looped, so that it will search for the value in cell A2, A3, and so on, until it reaches a blank.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Check [**How to ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) please

Comment: type `=`, go to the other sheet and select a cell. (It should make somethink like "Sheetname!Cellname"). Is this what you need?

Comment: Just record yourself using find and replace format then edit the code into a loop.

Comment: You can do the colouring in a `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop or a Find when you have Conditional Formatting.

```
Option Explicit

Sub colorIt()
    With Worksheets("sheet2").UsedRange.Cells
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
          Formula1:="=isnumber(match(" & .Cells(1).Address(0, 0) & ", sheet1!$a:$a, 0))"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End With
End Sub
```